# Self executing function passing object after condition

Tags: javascript, oop, parentheses

I have come across a self executing function that executes on a condition that the declared containing var exists, and if it doesn't exist it is passed an object.

Example:

```
var myFunc = (function(myFunc){}(myFunc || {}));
```

How come there is an "or" condition operator that passes an object ?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myFunc = (function(myFunc){}(myFunc||{}));
```

This doesn't make any sense because the myFunc Argument will always be `{}` - I'm confused by that.

Ill explain one that does

> First Example

```
var cool = {
   person: 'john'
};

(function( Argument ){
  console.log( Argument ); // Result Object {person: "john"} 
}( cool || {} ));
```

In this example cool is defined and is a object so it wont go past the `||`

---

> Next example

```
var cool;
(function( Argument ){
  console.log( Argument ); // Result Object {}
}( cool || {} ));
```

In this example cool is defined **But** the defualt value for a variable is `undefined`
so in this case it is undefined so Argument is a Object instead

Answer (score 6):

The code you provided is an example of the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html). In particular it's an example of [loose augmentation](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html#loose_augmentation) of the module pattern.

The module pattern is basically just an [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) which returns an object. For example:

```
// file 1

var MODULE = (function () {
    var my = {}, privateVariable = 1;

    function privateMethod() {
        // ...
    }

    my.moduleProperty = 1;

    my.moduleMethod = function () {
        // ...
    };

    return my;
}());
```

Augmentation allows you to split a module into parts. Each part can reside in it's own file. For example we can augment the above module as follows:

```
// file 2

var MODULE = (function (my) {
    my.anotherMethod = function () {
        // added method...
    };

    return my;
}(MODULE));
```

However in this pattern of augmentation `file 1` must be loaded before `file 2` or else you'll get an error. Loose augmentation allows you to load files in any order.

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {
    // add capabilities...

    return my;
}(MODULE || {}));
```

In the above example the module `MODULE` may be split over multiple files which can be loaded in any order. The expression `MODULE || {}` evaluates to `MODULE` if it exists. Otherwise it evaluates to `{}`.

Hence for the first file that's loaded the expression will evaluate to `{}` because `MODULE` would initially be `undefined`. In subsequent files the expression would evaluate to `MODULE`.

Comment: +1 for clear augmentation example. However I suppose the syntax `obj || {}` which you answered in last sentence was primarily questioned.